# Laravel select table columns with GROUP_CONCAT column

Tags: laravel

8
This is my query

```
$query = DB::table('hr_employees')
            ->select(DB::raw('hr_employees.id', 'hr_employees.employee_id_number', 'hr_employees.first_name', 'GROUP_CONCAT(hr_employee_daily_attendances.first_in SEPARATOR ', ') as tags'))
            ->join('hr_employee_daily_attendances', function ($join) {
                $join->on('hr_employees.employee_id_number', '=', 'hr_employee_daily_attendances.employee_id_number');
            });

        return $query->paginate();
```

This query return hr_employee.id only.
I need to get all specified column values

Anyone can help me?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I get it fixed by this query

```
$query = DB::table('hr_employees')
            ->select(DB::raw('hr_employees.id, hr_employees.employee_id_number, hr_employees.first_name, GROUP_CONCAT(hr_employee_daily_attendances.first_in SEPARATOR ", ") as month_days'))
            ->join('hr_employee_daily_attendances', function ($join) {
                $join->on('hr_employees.employee_id_number', '=', 'hr_employee_daily_attendances.employee_id_number');
            })
            ->groupBy('hr_employee_daily_attendances.employee_id_number')
            ->groupBy('hr_employees.id')
            ->groupBy('hr_employees.employee_id_number')
            ->groupBy('hr_employees.first_name');

        return $query->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score -1):

I have never seen a SELECT outside of a DB::raw command. Try moving the SELECT statement inside of DB::raw

Comment: thanks for your reply
can you please show how to rearnge this code?